# Как с команды ping на java взять time, TTL, byte и timestamp

Tags: java, ping

Пишу программу на Java, которая пингирует IP, и вот с результата мне нужно взять time, TTL, byte и timestamp, по дефолту выдает, например:
64 bytes from 87.240.131.119: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=38.6 ms
Код функции пингирования:

```
   static void runSystemCommand(String command, String addr) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String s = "";
            File file = new File("res//" + addr + ".json");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
            int i = 0;
            while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null && i < 2) {
                writer.write(s + "\n");
                System.out.println(s);
                i++;
            }
            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну пусть timestamp и time можно и так высчитать, но что делать с TTL и byte (насколько вижу, там все время пакет 64 бит отправляет, но не хочу магических чисел)?

Comment: Вы же получаете вывод пинга в `inputStream`? Формат вывода ping простой. Легко составить регулярное выражение и проверять по нему каждую строку `s`, извлекая `ttl` при совпадении

Comment: Спасибо. Но не получается... Можете показать пример как это сделать? С регулярными выражениями я только сегодня познакомился, раньше не приходилось встречаться.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Напишите вопрос с просьбой составить регулярное выражение для пинга. Вас непременно заминусуют, но с другой стороны найдётся кто-нибудь, кто поможет. Я хоть и не минусую, но и не составляю регулярки за кого-то.

Comment: Да нет, не для пинга, а как вырезать часть строки и сохранить. Хорошо, я понял

Comment: Регулярное выражение имеет строенную возможность выделять и извлекать нужные фрагменты. Иначе нафиг они не нужны. На самом деле что-то вырезать из строки не трудно. В Вашем же случае нужно из всего вывода ping отсеивать не нужные строки, потом искать части строки, отвечающую за нужные вам параметры, Вы сами-то видели что выводит ping:)? С помощь регулярных выражений это делается просто и за один раз выполняется и провера строки и извлечение всех параметров.

Comment: Вывод системной команды ping сильно зависит от системы и настроек локали. По этому если нет четкого ограничения по этим двум параметрам. Лучше не связываться с системными утилитами а взять программную реализацию. Например https://sourceforge.net/projects/icmp4j/